# React Native WebView reload on state change

Tags: javascript, webview, react-native

Error on line 9 
I need to change the state (url) for the WebView. 
These is an error for my first function...
Any help would be appreciated.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cU9qY.png)

*I'm fairly new to this*

I need the `TouchableOpacity` to change the url state on touch.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {View, WebView, Dimensions, AppRegistry, StatusBar, Text, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

let ScreenHeight = Dimensions.get("window").height;
let ScreenWidth  = Dimensions.get("window").width;

export default class dynamix extends Component {

  function setState(obj){
    this.state.url = obj.url;
  }

  function onPressButtonURL1(){
    this.setState({ url: 'url1'})
  }
  function onPressButtonURL2(){
    this.setState({ url: 'url2'})
  }
  function onPressButtonURL3(){
  this.setState({ url: 'url3'})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
      <View style={{height:ScreenHeight-100, width:ScreenWidth}}>
      <WebView style={{
          paddingTop:25,
          backgroundColor: '#f8f8f8',
          width:ScreenWidth,
          height:ScreenHeight,
        }}
        source={{ url: this.state.url }}
         />
      <StatusBar hidden />
      </View>
              <View style={{
                backgroundColor:'#131313',
                height:100,
                width:ScreenWidth
              }}>
              <View style={{
                width:ScreenWidth
              }}>
                  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onPressButtonURL1()}><Text style={{color:'#fff', padding:10,fontSize:15}}>"text1"</Text></TouchableOpacity>
                  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onPressButtonURL2()}><Text style={{color:'#fff', padding:10,fontSize:15}}>"text2"</Text></TouchableOpacity>
                  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onPressButtonURL3()}><Text style={{color:'#fff', padding:10,fontSize:15}}>"text3"</Text></TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
              </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('dynamix', () => dynamix);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, WebView, TouchableOpacity, Dimensions } from 'react-native';

const {
  height: ScreenHeight,
  width: ScreenWidth
} = Dimensions.get('window');

export default class dynamix extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      url: 'https://www.google.co.uk'
    }
  }
  onPressButtonURL = (url) => {
    this.setState({ url })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
      <View style={{height:ScreenHeight-100, width:ScreenWidth}}>
      <Text>{this.state.url}</Text>
      <WebView style={{
          paddingTop:25,
          backgroundColor: '#f8f8f8',
          width:ScreenWidth,
          height:ScreenHeight,
        }}
        source={{ uri: this.state.url }}
         />
      </View>
              <View style={{
                backgroundColor:'#131313',
                height:100,
                width:ScreenWidth
              }}>
              <View style={{
                width:ScreenWidth
              }}>
                  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.onPressButtonURL('https://stackoverflow.com')}><Text style={{color:'#fff', padding:10,fontSize:15}}>text1</Text></TouchableOpacity>
                  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.onPressButtonURL('https://www.google.com')}><Text style={{color:'#fff', padding:10,fontSize:15}}>text2</Text></TouchableOpacity>
                  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.onPressButtonURL('https://bbc.co.uk')}><Text style={{color:'#fff', padding:10,fontSize:15}}>text3</Text></TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
              </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('dynamix', () => dynamix);
```

Edit: I have just seen your attached image, the keyword `function` is throwing you the error.

If you go to [here](http://babeljs.io/repl/) and paste in

```
class Person {
  function setName(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

You'll see the `Unexpected token (2:11)` error. Removing the `function` keyword works.

Comment: Inside of your constructor, you should probably set the initial value of `url` via `this.state = {url: 'http//www.google.com'}` - Which line is the error being thrown on?

Comment: One more thing, `setState()` is a function within React, you should NOT provide your own implementation. Please see my revised answer.

Comment: see the new image link

Comment: Here's an example of your code: https://snack.expo.io/HJASrGsZZ - A demo you can play with, I removed your `StatusBar` component so you will have to add that. I made 1 function that takes a `url` param to modify state. Also in WebView `source` prop, it's `uri` not `url`. You also do not need speech marks around text within your `Text` component.